# How to remove a string in a list of list of string

Tags: c++

I tried to follow the erase example for sample iterator over list but I can't make it work.

Here is the code so far:

```
for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(), ; itr != listeOfListe.end(); itr++){
  if (condition) {
    for (list<string>::iterator it6 = itr->begin(); it6 != itr->end(); it6++)
    {
      itr.erase(*it6);
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
class "std::_List_iterator<std::__cxx11::list<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>>" has no member "erase"
```

Which indicates that it considers that `itr` is a list of list of string, why isn't `itr` simply a list of string since it iterates over `listOfList`?

Comment: You are trying to call `erase()` on the iterator itself, not the `list` it refers to.

Comment: Could you not do `if (condition) itr->clear();` rather than the loop?

Comment: @JavaRun note that the program doesn't really work, as it is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to call `erase()` on an iterator itself, not on the `list` that the iterator refers to.  That is why you are getting the compiler error.  You need to dereference the iterator via `operator*` or `operator->` to access the `list` to call `erase()` on.

Also, your inner loop is not accounting for the fact that `list::erase()` *invalidates the specified iterator*, so your use of `it6++` is *undefined behavior* after calling `erase(it6)`.  You need to use the iterator that `erase()` returns in order to continue the loop correctly, eg: `it6 = erase(it6)`.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
// pre C++11
for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
    if (condition) {
        list<string>::iterator it6 = itr->begin();
        while (it6 != itr->end()) {
            it6 = itr->erase(it6);
        }
    }
}

// C++11 and later
for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
    if (condition) {
        auto it6 = listOfStrings.begin();
        while (it6 != listOfStrings.end()) {
            it6 = listOfStrings.erase(it6);
        }
    }
}
```

Which simplifies to this:

```cpp
// pre C++11
for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
    if (condition) {
        itr->clear();
    }
}

// C++11 and later
for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
    if (condition) {
        listOfStrings.clear();
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
// pre C++11
if (condition) {
    for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
        itr->clear();
    }
}

// C++11 and later
if (condition) {
    for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
        listOfStrings.clear();
    }
}
```

I don't think that is what you are looking for, though.  Your title says you want to "remove a string from a list", so you are probably looking for something more like this instead:

```cpp
// pre C++11
for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
    if (condition) {
        itr->remove(string); // removes all matching strings
    }
}

// C++11 and later
for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
    if (condition) {
        listOfStrings.remove(string); // removes all matching strings
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
// pre C++11
if (condition) {
    for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
        itr->remove(string); // removes all matching strings
    }
}

// C++11 or later
if (condition) {
    for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
        listOfStrings.remove(string); // removes all matching strings
    }
}
```

Or, maybe you are looking for something more like this instead?

```cpp
// pre C++11
for (list<list<string>>::iterator itr = listOfList.begin(); itr != listOfList.end(); ++itr){
    list<string>::iterator it6 = itr->begin();
    while (it6 != itr->end()) {
        if (condition(*it6)) {
            it6 = itr->erase(it6);
        } else {
            ++it6;
        }
    }
}

// C++11 and later
for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
    auto it6 = listOfStrings.begin();
    while (it6 != itr->end()) {
        if (condition(*it6)) {
            it6 = listOfStrings.erase(it6);
        } else {
            ++it6;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, in that latter case, simplifies to this in C++20:

```cpp
for (auto &listOfStrings : listOfList){
    std::erase_if(listOfStrings, [](string &s){ return condition(s); });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note that behavior of this program is undefined.

```
for (list<string>::iterator it6 = itr->begin(); it6 != itr->end(); it6++) {
     itr->erase(it6); // !!
}
```

Code marked with `//`  invalidates iterator `it6`. Incrementing it in the loop is now illegal, since only valid list iterators can be incremented.

To correct the snippet, use following:

```
for (list<string>::iterator it6 = itr->begin(); it6 != itr->end(); ) {
     it6 = itr->erase(it6);
}
```

In this example, we use the fact that `std::list::erase` returns the iterator to the next element after the one erased.

However, this is only for illustration, assuming you would want to learn how to work with iterators. Better code would simply be

```
itr->clear();
```

Comment: @JeJo I intentionally ignored 'condition` bit, as it is not clear if it is even related to list contents. From the snippet, however, it is not clear how `erase_if` can help OP - seems like inner list items are cleared unconditionally, while outer list items are not erased.